# Unzip .gz file to /tmp location and delete unipped .gz file after the task

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script as follows for reading file line by line,

```
file= "/c/User/XXX/Desktop/XYZ.log" 
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if echo $line | grep  -Eq 'something' ; then

      [ do these tasks ]


    # define the log directory
    log_dir=/c/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Logs/"$DIR"/read_log

    # define the log file for this month
    log_file="$log_dir/rlog-$(date +%Y-%m)"

    # Create the log directory.
    if [ ! -d "$log_dir" ]; then
           mkdir -p "$log_dir" ||
                   die "failed to create log directory $log_dir"
    fi

    echo "variable" >> "$log_file"

    fi  
done <"$file"
```

Actually the file I am supposed to read is .gz file consists 
of single big file in it is located at some path /x/y/z. I want to know how to unzip this file to particular location /tmp and delete it at the end. I want to add unzip and delete tasks to my lines of code.

Thank you

Comment: Without the `-k` or `--keep` flag when running `gunzip` the original `.gz` file will be deleted when unzipping. So one of your requirements is solved by `gunzip` default behavior. As for gunzipping your one gzipped file to a specific directory, you can use the `-c` flag and redirect `gunzip -c myfile.gz > /some/file`

Comment: This looks wrong: `file= " /c/User/XXX/Desktop/XYZ.log"` -- you must not have spaces around `=` in an assignment, and I suspect the leading space in the file name is not what you want (you don't have a folder named " " in the current directory, right?)

Comment: @glenn , I have edited my post. It typo error. Sorry

Comment: you must not have spaces around `=` in an assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can extract tar file to `while` with `read` and process it line by line as required:

```sh
file=/c/User/XXX/Desktop/XYZ.gz
tar -xzf - $file | while IFS= read -r line
do
...
done
```

Comment: Got this error                                                                                                      
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get away with:

`zcat "$file" | while IFS= read line
do
...
done`

Which ought to be pipelined so you don't need a temporary file.

Comment: If you just zcat the file, do you get the expected plaintext? (e.g. `zcat "$file" | less` )

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear as to the content of the .gz file. Based on the fact that you mention a path, I assume that you actually have a `.tar.gz` file (i.e. a .gz file containing a .tar file which in turn has a single file packed into it, something like x/y/z/thefile.log).

In this case, you might not need to unpack to a temporary file, just do (-O tells `tar` to send the file(s) to stdout instead of saving them to disk):

`tar -O -zxf myfile.tar.gz | while read -r line ; do ...`

If you still want to save it into a temporary file (e.g., because you don't want to run 'while ...' in a sub-process):

```
tmpfile=/tmp/your-chosen-file-path
tar -O -zxf myfile.tar.gz >"$tmpfile"
while read ... ; do
done <"$tmpfile"
rm "$tmpfile
```

NOTE, either way this assumes there is just one text file in your .tar.gz archive (if there are many, all of them will get dumped to stdout by the `tar -O` command.)

Comment: File is like = shell.log.1.gz  [ inside of this archive there is single file called shell.log.1        and I am getting tar error ...tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: If the file is not a .tar.gz file, you should unzip it directly with ` gunzip <"$file" ` or ` zcat "$file" `, as noted in another answer. You can either pipe that directly into your 'while' command or save it in a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`zgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zgrep.1.html)

```
log_dir=/c/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Logs/"$DIR"/read_log
mkdir -p "$log_dir"
log_file="$log_dir/rlog-$(date +%Y-%m)"
file="/c/User/XXX/Desktop/XYZ.log.gz" 

if zgrep -Eq 'something' "$file"; then 
    echo "variable" >> "$log_file"
fi
```

Or, if you want to put something in the log file *for each line matched*, then:

```
zgrep -E 'something' "$file" | while IFS= read -r matched_line; do
    echo "variable"
done  >> "$log_file"
```

Comment: Hi Gelnn, I am getting invalid encoding and encryption errors after the execution of file. I can see the log folder but it has encoding and encryption issues

Comment: What are "encoding and encryption errors"? Do you know the encoding of the original log file? What is you own encoding (`env | grep 'LANG\|LC'`)?